# Can I convert a value of IntPtr to another IntPtr without unsafe in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

Suppose I have a IntPtr which was a void** get from native code. When I was going to deference it to a void* equivalence IntPtr I used such code:

```cs
unsafe
{
    var innerPtr = (IntPtr)outerPtr.ToPointer();
}
```

To do this I need to enable the `unsafe` code. I'm wondering if there is another way to convert this kind of pointers *without* unsafe?

---

Update:

Sorry for my question is invalid. The usage of `(IntPtr)outerPtr.ToPointer()` is meaningless.

Comment: An `IntPtr` doesn't know what it's pointing to - it's just encapsulating a memory address. So you can just do `var innerPtr = outerPtr;` (Microsoft should really have called this type something like `MemoryAddress` to make this clearer.)

Comment: What I want is to *dereference* the outer pointer, not just assign to another.

Comment: How can you dereference a `void*`? It makes no sense at all. You can only dereference a pointer if you know the type that you're deferencing it to... And there is no concrete `void` type. What is the actual type it's pointing to?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I have some misunderstanding at this point.

Comment: If you explain what you want to end up with (in terms of a concrete type, or perhaps just passing a pointer to a method) then perhaps we can help clear up any misunderstanding.

Comment: All I want is to avoid the unsafe keyword but it seems like I was using an incorrect method to do the deferencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(IntPtr)outerPtr.ToPointer()` doesn't actually do anything useful, the result still contains the same address.

If the equivalent of dereferencing a `void**` to a `void*` is what you want, you can use `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(IntPtr address)`.

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the functionality of the *ToPointer*. I will try your suggestion later.

Comment: `IntPtr.ToPointer` is just casting it to an unsafe pointer, nothing else.